# LibGdx Error parsing file

Tags: android, parsing, libgdx

I recently started a new game project through Android Studio and made a tilemap in a software called Tiled. However I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: assets/Desert.tmx
     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:83)
     at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:77)
     at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:65)
     at com.poptag.game.PopTag.create(PopTag.java:29)
     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: assets\Desert.tmx (Internal)
     at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
     at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.reader(FileHandle.java:163)
     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:81)
     ... 5 more
```

And here's code that loads and renders it:

```
@Override
public void create () {
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false,w,h);
    camera.update();
    tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("assets/Desert.tmx");
    tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
    tiledMapRenderer.render();
}
```

I have put the map "Desert.tmx" and the tileset "tmw_desert_spacing.png" into the assets folder for both Android and Desktop. When I run the launcher for the Desktop, I receive these errors.

> > [Here's the file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9LtE.jpg)

Comment: Could you give a file tree, libGDX project settings sometimes get mixed up in different IDE's

Comment: Are you sure you are exporting the map correctly? I know from the past that there are several different types of files you can produce with Tiled, when something is slightly off the parser cannot solve it by itself. However I did not use the build in importer much, I like to role my own.

Comment: I used all the major tile layer formats (XML, CSV, Base64) (Currently XML). The file type is definitely tsx which is needed to run with LibGdx.

Comment: Xml layer format is not supported. The stack trace clearly states that the file is not found. Typically, the `assets/` portion is not part of the path as the internal files are relative to the assets directory.

Comment: What would be the supported format? I tried all of them.

Comment: Anything but xml, but the format isn't the problem, as I already noted.

Comment: When I removed the asset portion, I still get the same error. When I removed the assets folder from the desktop project file, the same error appeared too. The file is present in the asset file however the emulator or android studio won't recognize it...

Comment: Set the working directory for you run configuration. It should point at the Android assets directory.

Comment: I changed the working directory of my desktop launcher to "C:\Users\Harry\AndroidStudioProjects\PopTag\android\assets", but I received the same error.

Comment: Actually... Now the error is referring to my tileset image.

`Error code:` Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: Program Files (x86)/Tiled/examples/tmw_desert_spacing.png.

Comment: I was using this tutorial [link] http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/04/16/LibGDX-Tutorial-11-Tiled-Maps-Part-1-Simple-Orthogonal-Maps.aspx

However, I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

Comment: You need that tmx file and tieldset (the picture) will be connected, via tiled program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I solved the problem. All I had to do was remake a map with Tiled and use a completely new tileset and it finally worked once I loaded the two files.

Answer (score 0):

In your:
tiledMap = new Tmxblabla.load(assets/Desert.tmx)
Shouldnt you load your file called Tiled here?
Otherwise i see no need of you referring to this file since it is not called to in your code.

Comment: Well, I'm not loading any files called Tiled. That was just a program that I used in order to create a 2D map. The file that I'm loading is the map called "Desert" which is a .tmx file located in the assets folder. However, Android Studio won't parse the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the map **.tmx** file
then you get tag  `tileset firstgid="1" source="grass_and_water3.tsx"` 
which is pointing to tileset **.tsx** file, and even **.tsx** file pointing to combined tiles image i.e. .png file

In order to solve this problem just keep all file in same location i.e. under asset/ and provide same path in all files (.tmx, .tsx etc)